# Easy linux installs on window machines

Tags: linux

I installed WUBI on my windows laptop. This is a simple installation of ubuntu that means I can easily boot up in Ubuntu without having to worry about partitioning drives.

Is their an equivalent of WUBI for any of the other linux flavours?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using virtual machines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. I made a search for you, on Google, and only found people asking if there's (or will be) a distro-agnostic Wubi equivalent (see [this page](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/12602)), and a guy asking if there's anything like Wubi for Fedora. Seems no luck so far.

As a poor surrogate, you could use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create a bootable USB stick in minutes or just run a [virtual machine](https://www.virtualbox.org/) (yeah, kind of obvious).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I googled as well and got nothing so tried here.

Comment: Well I think it would be a great idea to create a distro-agnostic Wubi equivalent, and it wouldn't be so hard, either...

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a generic version that will do all Linux flavours, but Debian and OpenSUSE have achieved some things.

The first is [win32-loader](http://goodbye-microsoft.com/), which mimics Wubi, in which you do most of the install from within Windows.

[image]

The other option is [Instlux](http://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Instlux), which is for OpenSUSE. I do not think it handles partitioning though, it just makes booting into the live image easier.

Wubi is great in concept, but it doesn't seem like others are ready to follow it quite yet.

Answer (score 2):

A WUBI for other Linux distributions? As far as I know: *no*.

*But* may I suggest you somethings easy to evaluate any Linux distibution?

1- Install Oracle VirtualBox https://www.virtualbox.org/

Just install Linux from the .iso file from your hard disk in a Virtual Machine

2- Install GetLinux http://getlinux.sourceforge.net/

Find and download .iso of over 100 Linux distros

Both are free and open source. Have fun!  :)